# Duplicate a Domino document in a web form

Tags: lotus-domino, forms

I have a Lotus Domino web application that uses plain old forms. The database already has some documents, and I want to clone one of the documents. So I thought that I could just issue an URL request like this:

```
/database.nsf/viewName?clone=12345678
```

This URL should open the form and prefill all form fields with those from the document with the ID 12345678. The user should then be able to edit all fields.

- At which point can I intercept the form creation?
- How do I access the newly created document that stores the form values?
- Can I do all this in LotusScript, or do I have to use the formula language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use an agent (Trigger: None). URL would be something like: /database.nsf/YourAgentname?OpenAgent&clone=12345678

In the agent you can get the parameter like this:

```
Dim ses as New NotesSession
Dim docParam as NotesDocument
Dim strQueryString as String

'- Get the parameter- document
Set docParam = ses.DocumentContext

'- get the querystring
strQueryString = docParam.getitemValue( "Query_String" )(0)

'- querystring will be OpenAgent&clone=12345678
'- here you can extract the id from the querystring
....

'- then you get the document (if 12345678 is the noteid e.g by db.GetDocumentByID( ) 
'- or if it is your own key by NotesView.GetDocumentbyKey()
Set docOrigin = ....

'- Now create a new doc 
Set docClone = New NotesDocument( db )
'- Fill the fields
Call docClone.ReplaceItemValue( "Field1" , docOrigin.GetItemValue( "Field1" ) )
'- Or all at once
Call docOrigin.CopyAllItems( docClone )

'- Here is the trick: Redirect to the new document using the agent output:
Print "[/" & db.HttpURL & "/_/" & docClone.Universalid & "?EditDocument" & "]"
```

The Brackets make the browser directly redirect to that page...

This code was just written from "memory" and might contain Typos / logical errors, but it should be a good starting point...

Comment: One "logical error" is that you are trying to redirect to a doc that has not been saved.

Comment: You are right... You might probably need to call a save somewhere... But I thought, that you can open "in memory" documents like this without saving them in web... But did not try it here...

Comment: `docClone` won't have a `Universalid` before it's saved. And "?EditDocument" will not work with unsaved docs. But anyway looks like Roland figured it out because he has accepted.

Comment: That's partially wrong... a document created via LotusScript has a Universalid from the beginning...

Comment: I think you will find that the UniversalID for the in-memory document could change when you save it.  (Not sure about that. It's been a long time...)

Answer (score 0):

Use `?OpenForm&ParenUNID=<unid>` to prefill with values from document with `<unid>`.